# Presto Query Optimisation

Tags: sql, presto

I have bunch of tables that I will like to left join them together. Does it makes any difference if I separate them by CTE?

Original

> SELECT * FROM TABLE A 
> LEFT JOIN TABLE B on col_a = col_b
> LEFT JOIN TABLE C on col_a = col_c
> LEFT JOIN TABLE D on col_c = col_d

or

> With table_1 as (SELECT * FROM TABLE A LEFT JOIN TABLE B)
> , table_2 as (SELECT * FROM TABLE C LEFT JOIN TABLE D)
> SELECT * FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2

Does this makes any difference in optimising the SQL queries? I am using PRESTO. Is the original better or CTE method by splitting the join or it makes no differences?

Comment: I'd be surprised if it made any difference. Keep your code clear and easy to maintain - KISS.

Answer (score 0):

##### Does this makes any difference in optimising the SQL queries?

In the provided example - no, [`WITH` Clause](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#with-clause) is used to simplify the queries for writing, not optimize them. Note that if the CTE is used multiple times in query it can have side effects:

> Currently, the SQL for the `WITH` clause will be inlined anywhere the named relation is used. This means that if the relation is used more than once and the query is non-deterministic, the results may be different each time.